# ConstraintValidator não retornando as mensagens de erro

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Estou criado uma validação de regras basicas de password e gostaria de fazer isso com o ConstraintValidator tentei implementar da seguinte forma.

```
public class PasswordConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidPassword, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidPassword arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String password, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        PasswordValidator validator = new PasswordValidator(Arrays.asList(
                new LengthRule(8, 30),
                new UppercaseCharacterRule(1),
                new DigitCharacterRule(1),
                new SpecialCharacterRule(1),
                new WhitespaceRule()));

        RuleResult result = validator.validate(new PasswordData(password));
        if (result.isValid()) {
            return true;
        }

        context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(
                        String.join(", ", validator.getMessages(result)))
                .addConstraintViolation();

        return false;
    }
```

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = PasswordConstraintValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidPassword {

    String message() default "Invalid Password";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

o código é executado porém não me retorna as mensagens de erro, ao debugar eu vejo que sim as mensagens existem.

Se trata de um projeto spring boot 2.7.9 e java 17.